# Bug in pandas.DataFrame.merge?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

The following:

```
q = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
r = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[5,6]], columns=['a','b'])
pd.merge(q, r, left_on=q.columns, right_on=r.columns, how='left')
```

raises an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The following doesn't:

```
q = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
r = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[5,6]], columns=['a','b'])
pd.merge(q, r, left_on=q.columns.tolist(), right_on=r.columns.tolist(), how='left')
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what is considered `array-like` in Pandas. It might also be a bug in documentation.

Pandas checks the type of `left_on` and `right_on` parameters (see `_maybe_make_list` function in pandas source), and since they are both not tuple/lists (namely, `q.columns` is `RangeIndex` and `r.columns` is `Index`), it basically does:

```
[q.columns] == [r.columns]
```

instead of comparing them directly, so that outputs the error.

Documentation [says](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) `left_on: label or list, or array-like`. I couldn't find a definition of `array-like` in Pandas, but in this case it seems to be limited to `tuple` or `list`.